# Reconciling %CPU with load average in top

Tags: cpu-usage, multithreading

We have a long-running process, which utilizes OpenMP to saturate all available CPUs with computations done in multiple threads (one for each core).

I'm looking at top(1) on a server, where the program is running on all 24 cores.

As one would expect, the %CPU column shows the process consuming 2380-2400% of the CPU. It's been running non-stop for a few hours already:

```
  PID USER  PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
27647 xxx   20   0 1416m 232m  11m R 2390.8  0.1   2324:59 pig
```

However, the load average fluctuates only between 9 and 11:

```
top - 19:22:37 up 25 days,  5:35,  5 users,  load average: 10.78, 10.24, 9.60
```

whereas I'd expect it to be hovering at or just below 24 as well.

Is %CPU lying to me -- with the process actually doing I/O over half of the time, but still reported as if running? Or is load average computed incorrectly?

This is on Linux, RHEL-6, kernel 2.6.32-696.6.3...